# What does "go down on the price" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idioms

See [this conversation](https://www.eslfast.com/robot/topics/shop/2shop07.htm):

> B: This t.v is $2500.
>
> A: You can't be serious.
>
> B: That's how much this t.v costs.
>
> A: That's too expensive for me.
>
> B: This television is of very high quality.
>
> A: You can't **go down on** the price.

The structure "**to go down on something**" does not exist in any dictionaries. However,

> we have "**[go down (on somebody)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/go-down?q=go%20down%20)**": (slang) to perform oral sex on
>   somebody (= to use the mouth to give somebody sexual pleasure)

I reckon this is some sort of creative use of the "**to go down on somebody**", so "**to go down on the price**" means "**to ease the price**" just like when you go down on someone you ease, please & give pleasure to that person.

What does "**go down on the price**" mean?

Comment: It might be easier to understand if it was written with a question mark, since the sentence is a question:
"You can't go down on the price?"

Answer (score 2):

The other definition of "to go down on somebody" you found is totally unrelated.

Basically, when prices go down, things are becoming cheaper. The numbers start out big (e.g, $50) and they end up small (e.g. $10), so they are going down.

For example, someone might say "That game costs $100, but I only have $50. I guess I will have to wait until the **price goes down** before I can buy it."

In your case, person A is asking whether the TV can be sold for any less money. "**On the** price" means "concerning the price", as in "We need more discussion **on the** matter."

Person B might respond "Sorry, that's as low as it can go", without giving any discount, or he might respond "Tell you what, I'll sell it to you for only $2000".

Comment: I would also mention you will often hear "come down" in this situation as well. For example, "I'll tell you what, I'll come down to $2000."